# How do we treat questions that ask us to write the code?

Tags: discussion, support

I was reviewing questions that arrived in my review queue, and this came up:

[image]

Ignoring the fact this question is ***very low-quality*** (could potentially be turned around by a through edit), it asks us to write the code for them.

I've recently rejected many similar questions as this , such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762501/push-sharp-notifications-and-tls#comment42114526_26762501) (slightly unfair, I admit), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762199/website-template-for-online-learning-similar-to-quizlet#comment42106402_26762199), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756612/usage-of-jira-api-and-pom-with-java#comment42095236_26756612).

I'm beginning to get tired of putting the same generic 'Stack Overflow isn't a 'write this question for me' site.' (as I have to write it out every time and not use the flags), but however I'm slightly confused how we should treat these questions.

Which flag option is the best to use in this situation?

Comment: @gnat Thanks for that, I looked for a possible duplicate and couldn't find any before asking this question. Seems like I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: "Unclear" is the choice I usually make.  "I need to do this." "Uh, it's unclear why you are here telling us.  *What have you tried, why isn't it working?* Without that information, we can't tell what's the problem."

Comment: I think "Too Broad" is the proper choice because it would require a complete feature or application to demonstrate an answer to the question. If it requires you to write a book to answer the question then it is too broad.

Answer (score 7):

The fact that someone is asking for code is not inherently wrong.  There are many different potential problems that the question could have, and the question could just as easily have no problems.  SO is here to answer practical programming problems.  That's sometimes going to involve writing code.

Don't ask yourself how to deal with questions asking for code.  Instead ask yourself whether or not the question meets any of the closure criteria.  Is it too broad; can you not provide a quality answer in a reasonably scoped answer?  Is it unclear what they're asking?  Does it lack sufficient information to be answerable?  Is it a duplicate?  If you answered yes to any of those, or for any other closure criteria, then close for that reason.

If you feel like commenting on the post to help the author determine how he can improve the question, then you're more than welcome to do so.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess the question *could* just be edited.